# wp_signon doesn't redirect to a page

Tags: wordpress, forms, redirect, authentication

I'm trying to make a login form using wp_signon. I'm new to WordPress. It doesn't redirect after it. My code is:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$creds = array();
$creds['user_login'] =$username ;
$creds['user_pass'] = $password;
$creds['remember'] = true;
$user = wp_signon( $creds, false );

wp_redirect('myurl here');
?>
<form action="" method="post"/>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/> 
    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edited: I added this after my code:

```
 if ( is_wp_error($user) )
 echo $user->get_error_message();
```

and when I try to log with username and password there is a message:

> ERROR: The password field is empty.
>   I enter correct username and password. What is this due to?

Comment: This is my whole code. Isn't it in the beginning of the page? How to fix it? :)

Comment: is there any plugin activated related to user login or authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

not too far off but you have a couple of mistakes.

1. Your form processing code and redirect would attempt to run whether there was post information received or not.
2. You need to manually exit the code after `wp_redirect`

You should also look at form security which i've not covered here.

```
    <?php

    if($_POST):

        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];
        $creds = array();
        $creds['user_login'] =$username ;
        $creds['user_pass'] = $password;
        $creds['remember'] = true;
        $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );


        if ( is_wp_error($user) ):
            echo $user->get_error_message();
        else:
            wp_redirect('myurl here');
            exit(); // you need to manually exit to get wp_redirect to work
        endif;  
    endif;

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post"/>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/> 
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/><br> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```